# Yii2: Passing index page to breadcrumbs in view and update actions

Tags: gridview, yii2, breadcrumbs, yii2-advanced-app

1) Have several pages of results in index (GridView) with default LinkPager settings.
2) Invoke either update or view actions in ActionColumn.
3) Do whatever, then click breadcrumbs to return to the same page in GridView you came from, but it does not: You're back at page 1 which in some use cases could be very annoying (of course one could simply and ungracefully just go back in browser but...).

So before working out some kind of unelegant $_GET-based solution, does anyone know any LinkPager (or related) pagination magic on this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no LinkPager magic to do this by now but I managed to find a solution avoiding controller tweaking. Just edit `view.php/update.php` and add before breadcrumbs stuff:

```
parse_str(parse_url(Yii::$app->request->referrer, PHP_URL_QUERY), $params);
```

Then in breadcrumbs:

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'myLabel', 'url' => ['index', 'page' => isset($params['page']) ? $params['page'] : '']];
```

Now everytime we click on `myLabel` breadcrumb we will be sent to the proper page in GridView we came from.

The main drawback is there is no page tracking beyond the second step, so if you do: `index --> view/update/create --> !index`, page tracking will be lost so better use a session variable as follows:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new BibliografiaSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    Yii::$app->session['myPage'] = Yii::$app->request->get('page');

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Then in breadcrumbs:

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'myLabel', 'url' => ['index', 'page' => Yii::$app->session['myPage']]];
```

This way the page number will be kept anytime;

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be useful for you :

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'YourLabel', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' =>  Yii::$app->request->get('page'), 'url' => ['index', 'page' => Yii::$app->request->get('page')]];
```

Comment: Thanks but though `Yii::$app->request->get('page')` is useful it does not solve the problem of getting this value into view/update as it is not available in there.

Comment: If it's useful please reta it for the update you need manage the page value and pass to the controller for render in update View

Comment: I'm not searching for a $_GET (or a derivative) way of doing things through controller/view (which I know) but a way of having such a parameter generally available through controllers/views.

Comment: Something similar to the use of `params.php` (which is just read-only). I know there is a `Yii::$app->view->params['myParam']` but I'm still struggling to find out whether it will fit this case.

Comment: Why not `$this->params['myParam']` inside your views

Comment: Because it seems not to work. I put  `$this->view->params['page'] = Yii::$app->request->get('page');` inside `actionIndex` controller method then I call `$this->params['page']` inside `view.php` and it throws an `undefined index: 'page'` error.

Comment: I think you need set the index: page with your values